# Pinata: How to add files to an existing folder

Tags: javascript, ipfs, pinata

I found out a way to add files to an existing folder with IPFS thanks to this question:
[IPFS: How to add a file to an existing folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803954/ipfs-how-to-add-a-file-to-an-existing-folder)

but I was wondering if there is a similar solution using Pinata service？

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not at the moment. IPFS is immutable so folders and files cannot be altered after being shared. IPNS is a subset of IPFS that is not supported by Pinata due to its slow speeds and the time it would take to create the infrastructure for it.

Answer (score -1):

When you update your directory, push the new directory to Pinata via their pinning service like normal. Then, combined with [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803954/ipfs-how-to-add-a-file-to-an-existing-folder) you'd update your new IPNS address to point to the new CID.

This way you can share the single IPNS address, still update the contents, and Pinata will still have your data available to be served.

Comment: Pinata might not do it as a service but [w3name](https://web3.storage/docs/how-tos/w3name/) does.